# XRDP - no matter what I do I can not make it work in 18.04 and Win10

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

I am not able to establish a connection between Win10 desktop and Ubuntu 18.04 via xrdp.

I have tried complete installation scripts and the only thing I am getting is either a green screen and an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8PWB.png) after a couple of minutes or an immediate disconnect from the Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, check which version of Ubuntu 18.04 you are running...  To check this, type in a terminal the following command

```
lsb_release -sd
```

If you are running **Ubuntu 18.04.3**, there is a known issue with xrdp package provided by Canonical (more info at https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390).  The xrdp package cannot install the xorgxrdp package because of failed dependencies.  This might be why you cannot connect remotely to your Ubuntu.

**Best option -  Install the new xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 package**

Install the new xorgxrdp package by issuing the following command

```
sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04
```

This should fix your issue

**Dirty Quick Fix - Downgrade xorgxserver package**

We assume that you have already installed xRDP package and you want to fix it

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Hope this help

Till next time

See ya